# How to Migrate test from LAMS to MOODLE

Tags: testing, import, export, moodle

We are migrating from LAMS to MOODLE.  I have to migrate questions from LAMS to Moodle.  When I try to export from LAMS I am getting .ims files.  Which cannot be imported in Moodle.

Please guide me how to export test from LAMS and Import to Moodle.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out this page: http://wiki.lamsfoundation.org/display/lamsdocs/Install+Moodle2+LAMS+Plugin

"The Moodle 2 integration is a stable release since Jan 17, 2012"

According to the plugin info page: http://wiki.lamsfoundation.org/display/lamsdocs/Moodle+2+plugin+development

There are plans to support "Backup and restore". But I don't know that status of that. Hope this gives you a good starting point.